# Git hooks post-commit поиск и замена текста в файла

Tags: git, bash, githooks

Задача состоит в том, что бы после коммита прописать количество ревизий в нужные файлы, а именно `Repodir/ecap/VersionFrame.asp` и во всех файлах `AssemblyInfo.cs` рекурсивным поиском в директории `Repodir`, пути все должны быть относительными от файла post-commit, лежащий в `Repodir/.git/hooks`, с `VersionFrame.asp` разобрался работает как надо, ниже содержимое файла `post-commit`

```
#!/bin/sh

commit_count=$(git rev-list --count HEAD) 

sed -i "s/revision:\s*\?[0-9]\+/Revision: $commit_count/gI" $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/ecap/VersionFrame.asp
```

а вот с `AssemblyInfo.cs` туговато мне. Если запустить `bat` файл из каталога `Repodir` со следующим содержимым (нашел на просторах)

```
echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('"dir /B /S | findstr /E "AssemblyInfo.cs""') do (
echo %%I
)
```

то мне правильно находит все файлы, в которые мне надо прописывать номер ревизии, остается переписать этот скрипт так, что бы он работал из `Repodir/.git/hooks`

Answer (score 2):

Сам решил, может кому полезно будет

```
#!/bin/sh

commit_count=$(git rev-list --count HEAD) 
sed -i "s/revision:\s*\?[0-9]\+/Revision: $commit_count/gI" $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/ecap/VersionFrame.asp
find . \( -name 'AssemblyInfo.cs' \) -type f -exec sed -i -r "s/(AssemblyVersion)\(\s*?\"([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+)\"\s*?\)/\1\(\"\2.\3.\4.$commit_count\"\)/gI" {} \;
```